# reactjs - putting props into the export params

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building form components - and I want to be able to give my own unique identifiers in the exports param. I also want to learn how to push validation schemas into these export sections. I need to get more control in this section otherwise all forms are thinking they are the "'syncValidationForm'"

```
import React from 'react';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

import validate from './validateForm';
import warn from './warnForm';

import FieldMaker from './FieldMaker';
import ButtonMaker from './ButtonMaker';

const FormShell = props => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <FieldMaker fields={props.fields} />
      <ButtonMaker buttons={props.buttons} pristine={pristine} submitting={submitting} reset={reset} />
    </form>
  )
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'syncValidationForm', // a unique identifier for this form
  validate, // <--- validation function given to redux-form
  warn // <--- warning function given to redux-form
})(FormShell)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a factory function and export it:

```js
function makeForm(id) {
  return reduxForm({
    form: id, 
    validate,
    warn
  })(FormShell)
}

export default makeForm;
```

And then you can create a form with custom `id`:

```js
import makeForm from './FormShell';

const FormShell = makeForm('syncValidationForm');

// ...
```

Comment: it seems FormShell can be passed these params and form will pick it up

Comment: <FormShell 
                initialValues={this.props.initialValues} 
                fields={this.props.fields} 
                buttons={this.props.buttons}
                form={uuid()}// a unique identifier for this form
                validate={this.validateHandler}// <--- validation function given to redux-form
                onSubmit={this.submit}
              />

Comment: I've found a bug -- where -- if I make the uuid -- it seems ok when there are two forms on a page --- but I opened up the login form in a modal - and the uuid changed when I tried to set an input

Comment: You should create uuid in `constructor` instead `render()` because `render()` may invoke multiple times.

Comment: ah - good idea - let me try it -- is there a react sandbox where I can just push this stuff in - not found anything decent to be able to fork and show

Comment: that worked - it stabilized it - I wonder why the form was getting re-rendered in that modal on touching on the inputs

Comment: there was another form in a modal - that wasn't affected - so odd